# Is it okay use NSDictionary as a parameter in protocol method?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I want to pass NSDictionary containing values using a protocol method to a view controller and was wondering if it is okay to do it or i need to use (id) and then in my view controller where i define the protocol method typecast the (id) to NSDictionary? 
Anyone, Thanks

@protocol TestDelegate

@optional

```
-(void) didFinish:(NSDictionary*) finishList;
```

or

```
-(void) didFinish:(id) finishList;
```

@end

```
//Someviewcontroller.m
-(void) didFinish:(id) finishList
{

NSDictionary* testDc = (NSDictionary*)finishList;
```

}

Comment: It is perfectly fine to send any object, so NSDictionary, as an argument in protocol methods if you are sure about the type of arguments are the same. if you are not, just use id as argument type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's totally ok to use a NSDictionary, or whichever type of object you want to send to your method, it's a common thing.

I would only think in using id if you dont know what kind of object you are sending.